# How to loop through Json pages with a cursor or pagination key

Tags: php, json, api, loops, pagination

I am working with a API which gives me a 100 names per json page, along with that it gives me a cursor which has a pagination:key to go through the other pages and check another 100 names with another pagination:key and e.t.c... The API will always give you another pagination and key in each page even if you reach the end of the "names". So the array with the "names" will look like data[]. My problem/question Is there a way to loop through these pages This is my code so far:

```
$channelsApi = 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows?to_id='.$rid.'&first=100';
$channelName = '';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: Bearer ".$_GET['fragmentaccess_token'].""
        ),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => $channelsApi . $channelName
    )
);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
// echo $response;
$json = json_decode($response, true);
```

I was able to make it through other pages if i simply did

```
foreach ($json['pagination'] as $curs){
    if(isset($curs) && $json['data'] != NULL){
        //$connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","","twitchun");
        $channelsApi = 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows? 
        to_id='.$rid.'&first=100&after='.$curs;
```

But i do not want to copy paste my code a million times if i have to go through a million names.

I have seen other posts where they use :do while: in php, but I was a little confused to how exactly to do that!

I am really in a dead end, so any advice is a great help for me!

EDIT : This is how the json response looks like

```
flyyrossi{"total":26,
        "data":[{"from_id":"262922764",
                "from_name":"goddessmiseria",
                "to_id":"228906764",
                "to_name":"BaychevLive",
                "followed_at":"2018-11-19T00:37:21Z"},
                {"from_id":...

    ...,"pagination":{"cursor":"eyJiIjpudWxsLCJhIjp7IkN1cnNblahblahblah"}}
```

To access the next I need the $channelsApi + the pagination in the json to go to the next page with "from_name".

My Overall problem is I want to get All of the "from_name"s.

Comment: It is really not clear what your problem is here. What are you trying to process from the json, can you show at least a small example

Comment: Is it clear after the edit ?